# Categories are not appearing when editing products

Tags: admin, categories, magento

I am using Magento Enterprise and only the top level category is available to choose when I am editing a product. All the sub categories are active and appear in the navigation menu, but not when editing a product.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Chris

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem with my Magento 1.5 installation. 
During the next 12 hours I will post a solution here :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was too busy today. Will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2 installs we had this issue. The 3rd time was done by downloading Magento directly from the server using wget command and then extracting and installing. Then it worked. I think whoever installed it the previous 2 times downloaded it to their desktop and then ftpd it up to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed - I had this issue after FTPing the Mage files.

After a wipe and re-install using hosts' script the issue is sorted. Shouldn't be necessary...

Answer (score 0):

A matching flaw appears to exists in 1.5.0.1 of Community Edition, in the CE version its a regression in the getSelectedCategoriesPathIds() method of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Categories

Reverting to the 1.4.* code for this method appears to fix it, all credit to rrroulio for tracking down this one on the magento boards: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/316838/

The old 1.4 code for this method is as follows:

```
public function getSelectedCategoriesPathIds($rootId = false)
{
    $ids = array();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$this->getCategoryIds()));
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        if ($rootId && !in_array($rootId, $item->getPathIds())) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($item->getPathIds() as $id) {
            if (!in_array($id, $ids)) {
                $ids[] = $id;
            }
        }
    }
    return $ids;
}
```